# Regarding lambda functions

Tags: python, lambda

Is there a way to assign result of other `lambda`s into another `lambda`?

For example:

```
a= lambda x=int(input('Enter a number')): x*x
b= lambda x=int(input('Enter a number')): x*x
```

Now how can I pass the result of these two lambdas into a 3rd lambda which I want to return the addition of `a` and `b`

Suppose I gave 3 to the first lambda and 4 to the second lambda...
So I get the return values 9 and 16 respectively
Now in the 3rd lambda I want the sum of 9 and 16...

Is that possible?

Comment: `c = lambda x: a(x) + b(x)` That said, this is specifically against [PEP Guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations). "Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier"

Comment: @HenryEcker rather `c = lambda: a() + b()` or for values `3` and `4` it could be`c = lambda: a(3) + b(4)` but it is still unreadable :)

Comment: you assing function to `a` and `b`, not results from these lambdas. To get results you would have to use `()` on lambdas - `a = (lambda x=int(input('Enter a number')): x*x)()`

Comment: this method has one minus - it runs `input('Enter a number')` at once and assings result to `x`. It doesn't wait for runing `a()`. And when you run `a()` then it doesn't run `input('Enter a number')` again. It runs like to lines of code - first `val = int(input('Enter a number'))` (which is executed only once - at start), second `a = lambda x=val: x*x` which never runs `input()`

Comment: @furas you are correct. I should've said `c = lambda x, y: a(x) + b(y)`. Or with the edit of x=input it should be `c = lambda: a() + b()`. But again, this is something that should not be happening regardless.